# Redirect through DNS whilst hiding the landing server

Tags: domain-name-system

I have bought a domain and can modify its DNS, let's call it A (so I can change A, AAAA and CNAME).

Then I have another domain which I bought which came with some hosting space, call it B.

Is it possible to show some content hosted on B when accessing A (without showing to the user the address of B?)

Answer (score 1):

you can just create a CNAME record pointing to the second domain.

e.g create a record like

```
domain1.com   IN CNAME   domain2.com
```

and ask your users to use domain1.com

technically speaking, you setup everything on your domain "B".
and eventually, you just create a CNAME using the domain name of your domain "A", make it point to "domain B".

edit : nb, if you use SSL, you will have to have SSL certificates also on the CNAME (domain1) as well to avoid problems.

Comment: This works for "mirroring" the whole domain, I think, but I cannot point to a specific page of content on my target host space. 

Also, it seems that I can only do that (on my current provider) by giving a prefix of my first domain like xxx.domain1.com and not really just domain1.com

Comment: if you want to do it for specific pages/URL and not the whole domain, then you'll need to use some webserver tricks with virtualhosts or proxies (you can probably do it with apache)

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve this on DNS level as DNS only resolves hostnames to IP addresses. It's like a phone book.

If you need to offer `www.example.com/somecontent` from one server while rest of `www.example.com` is on another, you need to do this on HTTP protocol.

If your requirement is that the address of the other server must not be revealed, you need to set up a *reverse proxy*.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on the webserver level using (name based) virtual hosts.

Set DNS for both names to the same IP.

Configure apache with 2 (name based) virtual hosts.

domain1 has a document root of `/var/www-domain1`  and contains some directories, including one named /download - so the file system path to that folder is `/var/www-domain1/download`

Set up domain2 so that its document root is `/var/www-domain1/download`

What domain1 sees as http://domain1/download/foo.tar.gz  domain2 will serve up at http://domain2/foo.tar.gz

Another lazy way is to use symbolic links, if you tell the webserver to follow them.  You can also alias various directories, so if you install phpMyAdmin it can be available on http://anyofyourdomains/phpmyadmin but the files all live in /usr/lib/phpMyAdmin and that directory is simply aliased in.